# Hiding elements outside of bounds on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, resize

I'm trying to get a UIView to expand (with animation), sort of like an accordion menu. I can get the animation working fine however the issue is the subviews of the UIView are expanding past the bounds of the UIView.

For example, the view has an UILabel in the top-right corner with a height of 16. Assume the UIView height is 0 at the beginning of the animation. One would expect that the content of the view be hidden and gradually reveal as the UIView grows. Once the height has reached 8, for example, half the label should be visible. However that isn't the case - rather, the label is visible the whole time, regardless if it's height extends outside of that of it's parent view.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I had to set the `clipsToBounds` property to `true`. I spent some time googling before making the question but didn't have much luck until I saw it in the Related section of my question.